# table not updating on Modal Window close

Tags: modal-dialog, wicket

here

```
    userPageFindUserModal.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback()
    {
        public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target)
        {
            System.out.println("ssaIDLISTCON");

            userInformation = new WebMarkupContainer("userAttributeTable");
            userInformation.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            addUserInformation("test", "Massey", "J", "1234512", "Enabled");
                target.add(userInformation);
        }
    });
```

When I close my modal window I want to update the contents of the calling page... but it doesn't work.

When I refresh the page however it works, but the ajax isn't giving me access to the current page components.. How does this work with a modal window? Is the target for the modal window? or for the parent pages instance?

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you closing the window using 'userPageFindUserModal.close(target)' or using close button in corner? If you are using .close() this function might not execute.

Comment: Yes, im using .close.   the system.out displays, so it is hitting the function

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new WebMarkupContainer without adding it to the compontent tree?

Your page probably already has a 'userInformation' (on which you already called #setOutputMarkupId(true)):

```
public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target)
{
    System.out.println("ssaIDLISTCON");

    // userInformation = new WebMarkupContainer("userAttributeTable");
    // userInformation.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    addUserInformation("test", "Massey", "J", "1234512", "Enabled");
    target.add(userInformation);
}
```

Comment: I was doing that for testing.